# Custom Format decimal and currency in C#

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am retreiving following decimal values and  need to convert these values into string.

**// Percentage columns**

**column1:** Getting value as 0.08 and should display in the UI as 8.00%

**// Currency columns**

**Column2:** Getting value as 1000 should display in the UI as $1000

**column3:** Getting value as 3000 should display in the UI as  $3000

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
     String PercentageCustomFormat="{PercentageCustomFormat}";
     string CurrencyCustomFormat="{CurrencyCustomFormat}";
```

The  PercentageCustomFormat/ CurrencyCustomFormat should contan logic that if any column returns Null,it should display as "NA".

Retrieving:

```
      String.Format("{PercentageCustomFormat}", column1);
      String.Format("{CurrencyCustomFormat}", column2);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This url on msdn should help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to create your own implementation of [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.getformat.aspx) and `ICustomFormatter` and pass it to `string.Format`. This will  handle your custom formats based on the format string you pass in.

```
void Main()
{
    var formatter = new CustomFormatProvider();
    var formattedValue = string.Format(formatter, "A format {0:PercentageCustomFormat}", 8.0m);
}

class CustomFormatProvider : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
   public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
   {
      return this;
   }   

  public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider){
    if (format == "PercentageCustomFormat")
        return " ... your custom format ... ";

    return arg.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am expecting something like this : String PercentageCustomFormat="{0:P:"NA"}"; //not sure if this is correct
     
The PercentageCustomFormat/CurrencyCustomFormat should also contain if condition logic( ie.conditional operator ?:) that if any column returns Null,it should display as "NA".How can I achieve this?

Comment: You would put the "NA" logic in the `Format` method of the CustomFormatProvider by checking for `null`. Whatever you put after the colon in the format string is what is passed to the `format` parameter. Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do something like this:

```
percentageString = column1 == null ? "N/A" : String.Format("{0:P0}", column1);
currencyString = column2 == null ? "N/A" : String.Format("{0:C0}", column2);
```

I wouldn't think a custom format provider would be required here.